# Protractor: Select with angular translate text

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm using protractor and I have to .click() on a button selected by.partialLinkText. We use angular-translate like this:

```
a(href="/documents/Impressum.pdf", target="_blank", ng-click="closePanelByImpressum()") {{ "STARTPAGE.IMPRESSUM" | translate }}
```

How can I select with the translate-text?

```
element(by.partialLinkText('Impressum')).click().then(function () {
            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                var newWindowHandle = handles[1];
                browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
                    var promise = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();

                    return promise.then((url) => {
                        expect(url.endsWith("/documents/Impressum.pdf")).to.be.eql(true);
                    });
                });
            });
        })
```

Comment: Can't you just use a different locator? Give the link an id and get the element that way

Comment: I agree with @benjrb, though you shouldn't need to add any attributes.  Can you just use the `ng-click`?  i.e. `var el = $('[ng-click="closePanelByImpressum()"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `STARTPAGE.IMPRESSUM` binding (this is a key for a text binding that uses translation to return the right text in the right language).

Your selector could look like :

```
element(by.binding('STARTPAGE.IMPRESSUM'))
```